# Init container to be ran only once per deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I use initContainers inside a deployment. An init container is created for each pods.

It is possible to get only one init container for the whole deployment ?

edit:

use case: need to run some db migration commands before creating the pods. So i have put these commands inside init pods.

problems:
- each time a pod is created, the init container is created
- on scale up init container is created

solution:
I have finally found a good example for solving this problem in [this article](https://gaunacode.com/deploying-onetime-jobs-to-kubernetes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is not possible to have one init container shared by whole deployment (which by definition is impossible as the unit of workload scheduling in kube is a pod), there are things you can use to get a similar functionality easily.

One way to achieve this would be to have an init container on every pod waiting for a specific job to be successfully executed, and a job that would do the actual init logic.

Another one would be to use leader election among your init containers so only one executes and the rest just wait for the lock to be release before they exit successfully.

Comment: Thank you Radek 'Goblin' Pieczonka, your "leader election" solution is clear, it will work for my use case. Can you tell me more about your first suggestion ? I don't understand who will trigger the "specific job".

Comment: Also how would you handle the case of scaling up ? (i don't want to have an init container runned when a new pod is created)

Comment: in terms of not running on scaling, the first question is if you can check if the init logic did it's job already (ergo. make init safe to run again and just skip if not required). 

If you run this as a job rather then as an init container, you will not retrigger the job on scaling, which is pretty much why I would prefer having it as job.
You wrote that it is a PHP web app, can I safely assume that it can easily be deployed and run (in a broken state, returning 500) even before the migrations are run ? If so, consider running a job and having no init whatsoever on the app pods.

Answer (score 1):

No, pods are identical so if you use an init container it has to be attached to every pod in your deployment.
You're welcome to comment and tell us more about your use case, because it sounds like the problem you are trying to solve is not the best fit for init containers.

Comment: I have got a simple web app that needs db initialisation tasks (php artisan migrate, php artisan db:seed). I am sure it is a common use case, but i couldn't find any example to deal with this problem. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: There's a lot of missing data here to give a meaningful answer. Where is the db located? If it is not a part of the pod (which I assume it's not) the db init step should happen separately of the web app lifecycle, ideally once the db is created a job should trigger and perform the init once.